# Iterate List values in IModelBinder BindModelAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My api controller receives multiple x-www-form-urlencoded pairs. I need to implement binder and to modify received values while binding.

While searching did clarify many things it didn't get me further than this.

In `PathBinderProvider` I have:

```cs
public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
{
    if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(IList<Path>))
    {
        return new PathModelBinder();
    }
    return null;
}
```

In `PathModelBinder`:

```cs
public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (bindingContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
    }

    var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(modelName))
    {
        modelName = "model";
    }

    // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
    var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);
    if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    ...
}
```

`valueProviderResult` is always empty.

I see that bindingContext.ValueProvider has 2 items: FormsValueProvider and JQweryFormsValueProvider and they are populated but I do not know how to access them and their values.

I need to iterate over list elements and ultimately return new `List<Path>` collection.

**EDIT**

Here is sample request from Postman.
[image]

Controller method is very simple:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromForm]IList<Path> paths)
{
    foreach (var path in paths)
    {
        _thirdPartyApi.AddPath(path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo like below:

1.Model:

```
public class Path
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

2.CustomBinderProvider:

```
public class CustomBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType && context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Path))
        {
            var propertyBinders = new Dictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder>();
            for (var i = 0; i < context.Metadata.Properties.Count; i++)
            {
                var property = context.Metadata.Properties[i];
                propertyBinders.Add(property, context.CreateBinder(property));
            }
            var loggerFactory = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

            return new PathModelBinder(propertyBinders, loggerFactory);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

3.PathModelBinder:

```
public class PathModelBinder : ComplexTypeModelBinder
{
    IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> _propertyBinders;
    ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    public PathModelBinder(IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> propertyBinders, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) : base(propertyBinders,loggerFactory)
    {
        _propertyBinders = propertyBinders;
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }
    protected override Task BindProperty(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(modelName))
        {
            modelName = "model";
        }
        // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);
        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        if (bindingContext.FieldName == "City")
        {
            var CityName = "change";
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(CityName);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.BindProperty(bindingContext);
        }
    }
}
```

4.Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void Post([FromForm]IList<Path> paths)
 {
     //...
 }
```

5.Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomBinderProvider());
        });
        services.AddRazorPages();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

***Postman***:
[image]

***Result***:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Rena. I am using `CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0`. I have modified CustomBinderProvider like this:
`var loggerFactory = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
                return new PathModelBinder(propertyBinders, loggerFactory);`,
and PathModelBinder like this:
`public PathModelBinder(IDictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder> propertyBinders, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) : base(propertyBinders, loggerFactory)`
When I debug it seems that BindProperty method is never used. Why could that be?

Comment: Yes.For asp.net core 3.0,it is the right way to pass `loggerFactory`.I update my code, you could use my code to check where makes error.If still have problems,please share your code which could reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi Milan,Did my answer help you resolve the issue?If so,could you accept as answer?

Comment: Hi Rena, as I said in previous comment it did not help me solve my issue as it never enters/calls BindPorperty method. I had no time to test further, but as of now, my problem is not resolved.

Comment: Hi,Did you use my code?I have provided my whole code.And give the result gif.Are you sure that you register the model binder like my Startup.cs?Also,pass the data like my postman.