# How to access ModelBinderProviderContext in ASP.NET Core Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, controller, model-binding

I have some ASP.NET 4.7.2 code that I'm converting to .NET Core 5.

In a few places, existing methods require the ModelBinderProviderContext. I realize that this is set up in the Configuration startup pipeline, but is there not a way to access it from within a Controller's action method, too?

Edit: further details...

In my controller, I have a ModelBinderProvider thanks to constructor injection:

```
   private readonly IModelBinderProvider _modelBinderProvider;
   public MyController(IModelBinderProvider modelBinderProvider)
   {
       _modelBinderProvider = modelBinderProvider;
   }
```

But if I want to get an actual model binder so I can manually bind models, I have to do it like this:

```
var myBinder = _modelBindingProvider.GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext_goes_here);
```

But, I don't see where to get the ModelBinderProviderContext.

Comment: Hi @TimH, could you please share your scenario? What do you want to use `ModelBinderProviderContext` to do?

Comment: @Rena I have added more details. Basically I want manually bind a model.

Comment: Hi @TimH, What is your model like and what data do you want to post? Did you want to change the model data or did any other things for the model? Actually asp.net core has default model binding system to bind the model. In asp.net core, one of the ways to custom model binding is like:https://stackoverflow.com/a/60633074/11398810